# VBA - Multiple series to a chart

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make add two series to a single XYscatter chart via loop. Currently, my code creates two charts. The X values are constant but the Y values change so I added them to an array to preserve them.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim thearray(9) As Double
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, q As Integer
    For q = 1 To 2
        For i = 0 To 9
            thearray(i) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 20)
        Next
        Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "TEST"
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2:K2")
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = thearray
            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 4
            For n = .SeriesCollection.Count To 2 Step -1
                .SeriesCollection(n).Delete
            Next n
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I appreciate any help offered.

Edit: I tried changing

```
.SeriesCollection(1)
```

To

```
.SeriesCollection(q)
```

But it doesn't work.

EDIT2: I  figured it out. I took

```
 Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
```

Out of  the loop and replaced 1 with q in .SeriesCollection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that works.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim thearray(9) As Double
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, q As Integer
    Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    For q = 1 To 2
        For i = 0 To 9
            thearray(i) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 20)
        Next
        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(q).Name = "HFF " & q
            .SeriesCollection(q).XValues = Range("B2:K2")
            .SeriesCollection(q).Values = thearray
            .SeriesCollection(q).MarkerSize = 4
            For n = .SeriesCollection.Count To 3 Step -1
                .SeriesCollection(n).Delete
            Next n
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```