Create multiple series in a scatter plot
I am attempting to create a scatter plot with multiple series from the following table that extends to row 278:

I want to create a scatterplot that displays a new series for each row, where the Y-axis and X-axis values span the 10 years shown (2014-2023).
I recorded a macro of me manually adding two of the series:
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$3:$K$3"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$L$3:$U$3"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$4:$K$4"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$L$4:$U$4"

End Sub

I would like to make it so that the code will automatically create the 250+ series for each new row in the Spreadsheet. Any ideas on how to go about this? I have very little knowledge of VBA... Thank you!!!
I tried watching dozens of YouTube tutorials but none are targeted to this exact scenario.

Take a look at this question, then write some code. Then ask questions based on that code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757100/vba-multiple-series-to-a-chart

Conceptually:

Determine the first row of the data (myFirstRow)
determine the last row of the data (myLastRow)
use a variable n = 1 for the series number
Use a For loop for i = myFirstRow to myLastRow
inside the loop, address the rows with the variables

Inside the For loop you also need to increment the variable n to get the series number
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$" & i & ":$K$" & i
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n).Values = "=Sheet1!$L$" & i & ":$U$" & i
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
n = n + 1

